# Add foreign key to ApplicationUser from entity classes in another project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I currently have a setup where my EF6 Database models are in a project called **Entities**.  However I have another project called **Infrastructure** that defines an *ApplicationUser* class which inherits from IdentityIUser (standard MVC authentication module).

The **Infrastructure** projects knows about the **Entities** but not the other way around.  My web project only knows about **Infrastructure**.

What I want to do is add some foreign key references from a couple of my classes/tables defined in my Entities project to the *ApplicationUser*.  I can add a field ok but it will just be a standard string field and have no foreign key constraints.

Is this possible using Entity framework?  I've tried using Fluent annotations but can't figure out how to do it.

My migrations and DBContext are all defined in the Infrastructure project.

Project setup is:

```
Web
|
 Infrastructure
 | 
  Entities
```

My web project has no knowledge of the Entities project as I have a middle layer in infrastructure that does mapping from the Entity models for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a redundant ApplicationUser, DbSet, config etc. to your Entities project and set the relationship there. Then you could use code like this:

```
var infrastructureUser= await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
var entityUser = db.Users.Find(infrastructureUser.UserID);
myEntity.UserProfile = entityUser;
db.MyEntity.Add(myEntity);
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

You could also look at decoupling EF, but that's a lot of work. https://jinishbhardwaj.wordpress.com/2014/07/16/decoupling-asp-net-identity-2-0-from-entity-framework-in-mvc5-part-1/

Comment: Cheers.  I hadn't thought of that.  Would that try and create a new migration though for the new dummry entities I've just put in?

Comment: Can't remember if it did, but you could comment out the Up() code or just do a no change migration to make the model matchup: Add-Migration CreateUsers –IgnoreChanges

Comment: Hello, I'm very new to MVC and I'm trying to implement this solution to my exact same situation. Can you please elaborate on creating "redundant" classes like those?

Comment: Sure. Easiest route is to have your App context inherit from IdentityDbContext. If you separate them, you can add a redundant User class (or whatever) and map it to the AspNetUsers table and then make references to it from your app context classes. You need to add a DbSet and indicate the keys and field lengths etc either with attributes or fluent code.

Comment: I understand the idea, however I'm at somewhat of a loss on implementation. Would you be able to provide some pseudocode to illustrate? I comprehend the code in your original answer, I think, and it seems like I'll have a duplicate table of userids in my entity project. Is this correct?

Comment: No, there is no duplicate table in the database. You have duplicate classes, in different contexts, that reference the same table (AspNetUsers). IdentityDbContext automatically references this. So in the other context, you do a DbSet<User> Users that points to a redundant class with a ToTable("AspNetUsers").

Comment: Ah ok I understand now, sorry for the denseness I'm still trying to wrap my head around contexts vs models vs entities etc it's kind of overwhelming.

Comment: Here's a good post on Identity http://www.typecastexception.com/post/2014/04/20/ASPNET-MVC-and-Identity-20-Understanding-the-Basics.aspx#The-Heart-of-it-All---ApplicationDbContext

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95388/discussion-between-eschersenigma-and-steve-greene).